# Exchange DistributionGroup Alias vs. secondary EmailAddress

Tags: exchange-server, o365-flow

Where is the difference between

```
Set-DistributionGroup testgroup -Alias testgroupalias
```

and

```
Set-DistributionGroup testgroup -EmailAddresses @{Add="testdistributionlistalias@domain.de"}
```

Why documenation saying only 1 alias is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is because **alias** in the Microsoft Exchange context is different than generically saying **email alias**.

From the [MSDN Document on Active Directory fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/aa997251(v=exchg.65)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), you can see that aliases are stored in the **MailNickname** field of AD user objects and mail enabled groups and act as an alternate way for you to reference a user or group.

These are however different than what is set via the **-EmailAddresses** parameter.  These are full internet email addresses i.e. the-address@example.com and will work properly for both users in the Exchange environment as well as people in other companies/organization.

You can only 1 alias but you can assign many alternative email addresses.